# TextInputLayout in listview

Tags: android, listview, androiddesignsupport

When I use Material Design Support TextInputLayout in a Classic Layout, I have no problem, I get the hint animation.

But when I use it inside a listview, I lose this, and it behaves like a classical Edittext.

Why???

Here is my code ( one cell xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_valor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="test2"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/valor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="test"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cambutton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_azul_states"
        android:contentDescription="Tomar foto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_device_access_camera" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Initially, I had it with LinearLayout, I tried to use NestedScrollView, without success...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both hint in layout and call setHint only on TextInputLayout instance from code

**EDIT:**
I realized that my answer is wrong. My case is different because I use a RecyclerView, I've tried with the ListView and the animated hint just won't work...

I suggest you to convert to RecyclerView, it's easy and solves the issue

Comment: Is that a suggestion, or you are certain this will solve the problem?